# Is "Document Canvas " same as "Canvas Element"?

Tags: css, html, canvas

I am learning html and css from [this tutorial](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Main_Page). On the topic of [css layout model](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/The_CSS_layout_model_-_boxes_borders_margins_padding) different kinds of canvases are mentioned, like,

- browser canvas
- document canvas
- available canvas

As far as I know *Canvas* is a new element added to html5 with which we can *draw* shapes. Do the terms *browser canvas, document canvas,* and *available canvas*  refer to the html5 *[Canvas Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element)*?

Comment: Canvas in the context of css has nothing to do with the HTML5 Canvas object. Css is used to style HTML, but not HTML5 Canvas element.

Comment: @GjermundDahl Css **can** be used to style HTML5 Canvas element too. Check out this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/ModifyingtheCanvaswithCSS/ModifyingtheCanvaswithCSS.html) "_Because the canvas is an HTML element, you can use CSS styles..._"

Comment: I was inprecise. Css can be used to style the Canvas element, but not its content.

Answer (score 2):

The "browser canvas" does not exist. The description means the "viewport", but it's wrong. Block elements, like `<div>` is by default, take the full width of the content box of their containing block. Likewise, "available canvas" refers to the same concept.

By the "document canvas", the description means the [CSS canvas](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/intro.html#canvas) which is the full extent of the area on which all elements are rendered. The HTML5 canvas element is rendered on the CSS canvas, but so are all other elements that are not `display:none`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I think they are using an outdated or something similar terminology for _viewport_. They are using the same terminology in their [latest tutorial](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/guides/the_css_layout_model) too.

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS tutorials often use very imprecise terminology. I always prefer to go by the CSS specs (the 2.1 spec / 2.2 draft is a superb document that uses very precise language), however the price of that is that it's not an easy document to read. Often, it can take many readings and an understanding of the whole spec to fully grasp in the implications of much that is said there,